# How to freeze/fix the last row on a DT::datatable output in R?

Tags: r, datatables, dt

I have a datatable in my shinyapp with a lot of rows so i need to use the scrollY = TRUE option. Im wondering if there is a way to fix the last row so i dont need to scroll to see this specific row. I know this is easy to do with columns, but rows... not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to fix (the header and) the footer with the **FixedHeader** extension:

```r
library(DT)

dat <- iris

sketch <- htmltools::tags$table(
  tableHeader(c("",names(dat))),
  tableFooter(c(
    "", "this", "is", "my", "awesome", "row"
  ))
)

datatable(
  dat, container = sketch,
  extensions = "FixedHeader",
  options = list(
    paging = FALSE,
    scrollY = 300,
    scrollCollapse = TRUE,
    fixedHeader = list(header = TRUE, footer = TRUE)
  )
)
```